# Enabling mysql slow query log during a certain time

Tags: mysql, schedule, sql-scripts, mysql-slow-query-log

I would like to enable the slow query log during a certain time interval every day - 00:00:00 UTC to 00:10:00 UTC. Is there any method to enable the slow query log in such a manner?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do: Create two `EVENTs`.

- One to run daily at midnight; it will execute `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=ON`.
- One to run daily at 00:10, and set it to `OFF`.

Comment: Thanks! Will try the approach.